# set mail driver dynamically from database for different email in notification

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpmailer, mailer, laravel-mail

I want to set the following setting dynamically before I notify the user.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_SENDER_EMAIL=
MAIL_SENDER_NAME=
```

for each customer they have the option to set this value from the frontend now I need to send email as per there setting is there any way in laravel I can do this.

I am using notification to notify each customer so before I notify I want to set this option dynamically from DB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

these env variables then used in configuration file you can find right config names by checking `mail.php` in `config` folder

You can change config values at run time by array to config helper.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

You need to find corresponding variables and set their value like for Laravel - 6

```
config([
    'mail.driver' => 'smtp',
    'mail.host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',
    'mail.port' => 587,
    'mail.encryption' => 'tls',
    'mail.username' => 'if-any',
    'mail.password' => 'if-any',
]);
```

After that your new settings should be used.

Comment: if I modify config value than it also affects another email which is going from the system so it's not the best option to modify it

Comment: at one time there is a chance that different email will go from system

Comment: How this can be used by any other request as you will modify it on fly and you can re-change to default after shooting the email if their could be the any other email in same request.

Comment: Or you can see this api method: https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.html#method_mergeConfigFrom

Comment: in laravel notification in which file i can change this configuration ... inside Mail file or notification file ?

Comment: config is a global helper function, you can call it in whole app you can decide on your logic.

Comment: i mean i am using notification which is in queue so which file and function do you think i should write logic

$user->notify(
                (new Email($email))
            ->onConnection('redis')
            ->onQueue('high'))

Comment: Both will run in the queue job but I think it should be in notification file in this you can use your mailable in other notifications. 

Remember to undo the custom settings after sending the email because are long running threads it may persist custom settings in that queue worker.

Comment: yes in notification file where i can put undo logic?

Comment: i am confused because send method will call at the end so i am thinking i can not write inside any of this 2 file

Comment: You are right. I am not sure as I was sending email in custom job where I manually send the email with `Mail::send([],[],function(){})` in the handle method of job.

In this case I will be able to just update config before Mail::send method and would update again with default after send within that handle method of Job.

With Laravel's notification and Mailable yeah its confusing for me too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201160/discussion-between-zohaib-hassan-and-joy).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to create a `$mailer` and use it, then discard it.

```
    $swiftMailer = app('mailer')->getSwiftMailer();

    $transport = $swiftMailer->getTransport()
        ->setUsername($username)
        ->setPassword($password)
        ->setHost($host)
        ->setPort($port)
        ->setEncryption($encryption)
        ->setTimeout(30);

    $mailer = app(\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
    $mailer->setSwiftMailer(new \Swift_Mailer($transport));
    $mailer->alwaysReplyTo($reply_to);
    $mailer->to($user->email)
        ->send(new AdminPasswordReset($data));
```