# how can I access a variable which is passed from controller to view in helper function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have one view which is calling one helper function and in that function, I want to access the variable which is passed in the view from controller I tried use statemen but still, I am getting an error of undefined variable
here is my code.

```
return view('myview')->with([
            'myvariablename'     => true, ]);
```

below is code in my view file

```
@if(myHelperFunction()){
 // do stuff
}
```

here is my code in helper function where I want to use that variable which is passed from controller to view.

```
function myHelperFunction()
{

    if (isset($myvariablename) && $myvariablename) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(myHelperFunction()){
 // do stuff
}
```

is not a correct syntax for Blade, change it to

```
@if(myHelperFunction($myvariablename))
 // do stuff
@endif
```

And accept the variable in the helper function

```
function myHelperFunction($myvariablename)
{

    if (isset($myvariablename) && $myvariablename) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Because the helper function isn't in the view, it's in an autoloaded file, it has no way to know where `$myvariablename` is or where is it coming from

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks ..... I feel stupid now..... I was using use() to use that variable

Comment: btw can you help me with this also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461722/set-mail-driver-dynamically-from-database-for-different-different-email-in-notif/58461816?noredirect=1#comment103264513_58461816